# Inheriting a class where the class' __init__ calls internal functions

Tags: python, inheritance, initialization

I am going to inherit a class from a library but `__init__` method of this class makes calls some functions from its internal modules. However, I don't want to use these functions, too. Bear in mind that, I don't want to change any code in the library. I think, the library has bad design, calling specific functions in your `__init__` method does not make life easier for people who wants to use inheritance. If it's another method than `__init__` I could override the method but I need to call super from my class' `__init__` method.

Here is the some code to illustrate the situation. Let's start with the library:

```
# library: inside of module a
class BaseClass(object):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # initialize params
        from utils import some_func, some_dict
        some_func(...)
        for key in some_dict.keys():
            # do stuff


# library: inside of module utils
some_dict = {...}
def some_func(args): # do stuff
```

Here is my code:

```
# inside of a one module.
from A import BaseClass
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SubClass, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# Also I have implementation for the dict and some_func.
# inside of module a (my code not the library)
some_dict = {...}
def some_func(args): # do stuff
```

So, the problem is that if I do the call of the BaseClass' `__init__`, it will use their own implementation in their module, not my implementation for `some_dict` and `some_func` in module `a`. I have some solutions but I'd like to understand what's the best practice.

### Possible Solutions

**Use `__new__` method inside of the SubClass.**

```
class SubClass(BaseClass):
    # ...
    def __new__(typ, ...):
       import library.a
       from a import some_dict, some_func
       library.a.some_dict = some_dict # replace it with my dict.
       library.a.some_func = some_func # replace it with my function.
```

The downside: What if I don't want to change library's implementation for another method. Solution: I may change this temporary. After initialization, I can revert these values back. Maybe. Another problem is: what if I need to change these variables way before?

**Use my package's `__init__.py` to change these variables very beginning.**

```
# inside of `__init__`.py of my package. Very beginning. 
import library.a
from a import some_dict, some_func
library.a.some_dict = some_dict # replace it with my dict.
library.a.some_func = some_func # replace it with my function.
```

Is there any good practice for this problem? I think, for this case, I am okay to change the values of `some_dict` and `some_func` through the whole code execution, so which solution do you think can be better for which conditions? Am I wrong thinking that the BaseClass implementation is problematic since it's more complex than it should be (e.g., importing modules, calling functions from that internal modules)? I think it might have been better if they make these calls in a separate functions so that I could override it. Or, `__init__` can take dict and a function argument regarding these, so that I can provide it in object creation.

What's the best practice for this situation?

Comment: Good luck with this! That import in their `__init__` is evil. It's a shame you need to do that `super.__init__` call, but I guess the alternative is to write your own `__init__` from scratch that avoids super. I think your `__new__` solution looks good, but at this stage I can't decide what best practice is. If you can get this working correctly without creating total chaos I think you'll be doing pretty well. ;)

Comment: Yes I think the best thing is to not call super at all, but recreate the relevant parts in your own `__init__`.

Comment: @PM 2Ring, Thanks a lot! Yeah, I think it might be good idea to write my `__init__` function. I guess, I was mistakenly worried if I wouldn't do super call, I can't use `BaseClass`'s methods but it's `__new__` method's job, so it's safe to totally override `__init__` of the BaseClass (though, it's unfortunate). One problem is that I have to override `__init__` if I want to use this BaseClass for inheritance. I think a little bit more on Monday (no work today ;) -- except this I guess), or either `__init__` or `__new__` and fork this library and de-couple problematic code & send a PR.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, Thanks. My concern is the same as my response to PM 2Ring. I will think a little bit more if I can do any better; if not, I'll either implement `__init__` from scratch or go with the `__new__` and suggest some code changes to the library via PR.

Comment: What you want is simply not inheritance: what would you say if all the relevant code you was inline inside `BaseClass.__init__` and was too complicated to repeat?  There simply is no clean way to *pretend* that `library.a` provides extensibility that it doesn’t.  Not that that makes your desire unreasonable: maybe they *should* provide that feature.

Comment: @DavisHerring, Thanks. Yeah, I thought using composition instead of inheritance, too. However, inheritance suits better in this problem (sorry to lack of context above to justify why it's better). I checked the library's last version, and they refactored these problems. We were using pretty old version, after mid-level refactoring, I will move to their new version with a major refactoring. Luckily our code base relatively small. Thanks a lot again for good suggestions!

Comment: @Baskaya: Good—although there is no real difference here between composition and inheritance.  Both are equally hamstrung by inextensible design of the code to be reused.